# Atomic Set with basic check on old value

Tags: rust

Is there a way to atomically set a cell based on the previous value in the following way?

There are three operations, each of which set the cell based on the current value and retrieves the old value. I've indicated what it should set based on the old value as `old => new`:

Operation 1:

```
0 => 1
1 => 1
2 => 2
```

Operation 2:

```
0 => 2
1 => 1
2 => 2
```

Operation 3

```
always set to 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Those first two operations are examples of changing only one original value to a new one, i.e. a compare-and-set, which can be done in Rust atomics with [`compare_exchange`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU8.html#method.compare_exchange):

```
let _ = atomic.compare_exchange(0, 1, Ordering::…, Ordering::…);
```

```
let _ = atomic.compare_exchange(0, 2, Ordering::…, Ordering::…);
```

And of course the third is just [`store`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU8.html#method.store).

Comment: Ok, does this get compiled down to down a single atomic hardware instruction?

Comment: @Test: In a word, yes (you can check)

Comment: Where can I check? More than that, where can I check what the expected latency should be (or clock cycles or whatever)

Comment: This seems to take ~8ns and even fetch_add (which seems more complicated) is only 6ns. Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: @Test: There’s probably a faster way to achieve whatever your use case is, but I’m not aware of a faster way to do exactly the same operation in isolation.

Comment: @Test both `compare_exchange` and `fetch_add` compile to a single instruction: `lock cmpxchg` and `lock add` respectively (or `lock inc` if adding a one). You are hitting the bounds of what your CPU can do; I believe the former is slightly slower because it contains a conditional check.

Comment: @Test *Where can I check?* - godboolt is a popular choice: https://godbolt.org/z/PYKc76nba

Comment: @Test Note that on modern ARM `fetch_add()` is a single instruction but `compare_exchange()` is not.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman where can I find a list of the single instructions on ARM and non-ARM?